# What is the data structure of this string, used to render webpage charts? Does not seem to be svg path

Tags: data-structures

An API's response JSON string contain the following:

`"user_index": "7.88413374111.4681.4.7U84.76Q4657.469U.461654.8114.15Q......"`

It seems to be used to render a chart on a web page.  What's the data structure?

**Edit: added more information**

The source URL is: [index.baidu.com](http://index.baidu.com/?tpl=trend&word=taylor%20swift). Unfortunately, you have to register a (free) account and log in to use the site.

What I want is to get the data shown in the image below

[image]

When you hover over the chart, you will get a score of that day.  This chart describes trends of Taylor Swift.

The XHR response data I made [a gist here](https://gist.github.com/fanweixiao/9533725)

This chart seems to be using SVG.

Comment: Are you going to tell us which API or should we keep guessing :-)

Comment: The web url is: http://index.baidu.com/?tpl=trend&word=%C1%BD%BB%E1, you can check XHR request:) Sorry I didn't post the source url.

Comment: Your URL you've provided doesn't work and the question is extremely unclear anyway. Could you add any further detail to the question e.g. the (previously mentioned) API you are dealing with and providing any source code applicable, what sort of "chart" it creates. The data has also been truncated so it wouldn't be possible to give a definitive answer so technically I'm correct stating it's an "alphanumeric string" in a (potentially) proprietary format (it's not hexidecimal, octal, binary or even latitude/longitude). The full JSON structure might also help give more context to your question.

Comment: It's in Baidu word trend format (resistance was futile)

Comment: Your JSON example is still woefully incomplete. Your link requires a login. There's no point putting a bounty on a bad question. You'll only get answers by providing more information (a bigger sample of data, a working, public URL, etc).

Comment: Oops, sorry for lack of information, I've edited questions, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with a link to jsfiddle that decodes Taylor Swift data that you had in the sample request:
http://jsfiddle.net/pFV7p/2/ (start with the end of the output to compare to last dates on the chart).

Here is how the chart looked to me:
[image]

So I've spent some time investigating how it works (I find decoding stuff really exciting challenge :) ) and I have come to some conclusions which may help you to decode the data.

1) Pay attention to the file fun.js?140221 from
    http://index.baidu.com/static/js/funs.js?140221

2) After de-obfuscation, find these two functions in the source:

```
function b(p, m, o) {
    var l = c(m || "tyufCBJKQas", o || k || a);
    p = p.split("");
    for (var n = p.length; n--; ) {
        p[n] = l[p[n]]
    }
    return p.join("")
}
function c(m, o) {
    m = m || "k";
    o = ((o || "") + m).split("");
    var p = m.length;
    var q = 0;
    var l = {};
    for (var n = 0; n < o.length; n++) {
        if (!(o[n] in l)) {
            l[o[n]] = q;
            if (++q >= p) {
                l[o[n]] = ",";
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return l
}
```

They do the decoding stuff. Function c builds the "alphabet" and function b does the actual decoding. One of the keys for decoding is "tyufCBJKQas" and the other two are in variables `k` and `a`. Basically to decode the userIndexes you'd need to know what key should be in the variable `k` (because if `k` is set, `a` is not used, and as far as I tested - `k` is always set).

3) Pay attention to url used when requesting the data.

The request is sent in similarly to this one (which might be expired by now):
http://index.baidu.com/Interface/Search/getAllIndex/?res=gxIWXSIBDCczDANlWGpCCUUQYXYgADdtLlgmdxc2IzEjVA9OPwEAPGUWGhEKJC8AIDwtDzMeKF5QAEsvLg4PaEYlKyRmGQY7AlcmLg4%2BSTsTAjUwYz0TQSQcLR04JhExfFRIKUs0LENiVAQvIiAhECAmZSFKKzAKZ10pAVkVGnJXCQcmPnhuQVgHLXwnGAtmBTczdDF%2Bf0EqDAcMOCQgdB5EGiQMHXwzB2FVFXkxNTwkNHgwAFx2AhItDFUEW1UEckcgZn08AR5mfxUBPw%3D%3D&res2=12EXSTREXSTR4.962418.408N0QI0bMRC6i2ZfuiaiBEsFk3dWZSOOR7rUjv107q2CvEc6L5cZ

In this case parameter res2 equals to "**12EXSTREXSTR4.962418.408N0QI0bMRC6i2ZfuiaiBEsFk3dWZSOOR7rUjv107q2CvEc6L5cZ**" That is important because before mentioned variable `a` tends to be equal to res2 parameter.
Too bad we need variable `k` to decode, which often is very different from `a`, but sometimes it is quite similar, as in this case. For this request it was "**12EXSTR4.962418.408N0QI0bMRC6i2ZfuiaiBEsFk3dWZSOOR7rUjv107q2CvEc6L5cZ**". Which means that perhaps variable `k` can also be calculated from the request itself.

4) To create working solution that can decode the data every time, you just need to find where variable k is assigned and what is the algorithm for it's value. When you do that - use similar code to what I have in the fiddle with the right value for k and userIndex.

NOTE: Considering the fact that baidu has implemented some custom data encoding/decoding algorithm I suspect that they are not very happy by the fact that someone would use their engine directly, so perhaps you should pay attention to whether you break their user agreement, usage rules, etc and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably they are using a javascript chart library (e.g. [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html)) and updating their data using an ajax.

Data structure should hold labels and other information. Control that page and see which charting library they use. You should be able to see network calls using your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I've found they use Raphaeljs for SVG rendering, and still trying to find something from the obfuscated javascript codes...